# storing a value from a table using webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to store a column value from a table using Webdriver. I can do easily using Selenium IDE using store and echo commands but in Webdriver how to achieve that. I am little new to this so dont know its complexity. Here is the source code for web page:

```
       <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Service</th>
                                                    <th>Provider</th>
                                                    <th>Start date</th>
                                                    <th>End date</th>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>BASICSW (no description available)</td>
                                                            <td>DELL</td>
                                                            <td>
24-07-2009                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>25-07-2012</td>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>POW (Parts Only Warranty)</td>
                                                            <td>DELL</td>
                                                            <td>
24-07-2011                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>25-07-2012</td>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>NBD (Next Business Day on-site)</td>
                                                            <td>DELL</td>
                                                            <td>
24-07-2011                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>25-07-2012</td>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="5" style="background:none"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                            </tbody>
```

I want to store the vallue of column End Date , ie 25-07-2012, for further use. But How to do that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the nth-values of the column you need with selector like this:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tbody tr td:nth-child(3)"));
```

Note that its `findElement*s*()`, therefore, as result, you will have list of all the end date column values.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the best solution. I think its good idea for beginners. 
I used Selenium IDE to store the text and do a echo of it. Then I exported this content as Java Webdriver-Junit file, and copied the code to my Webdriver script. This worked fine. Thanks anyways all.